# undefined variable in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, From My senior i got one task to solve existing undone internal project. and develop that project again.
i am having query when i am ruinning this project.
here i am pasting my 2 view files.
tell me if any one required further files.

Thank you in advanced.

TODO DropDown View

```
    <!-- BEGIN TODO DROPDOWN -->
    <?php
                if (isset($pendingtask)) {
                    ?>
    <li class="dropdown" id="header_task_bar">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
            <i class="icon-tasks"></i>
            <span class="badge"><?php echo  count($pendingtask); ?></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu extended tasks">
            <li>
                <p>You have <?php echo  count($pendingtask); ?> pending tasks</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu-list scroller"  style="height:250px">
                <?php
                if (!empty($pendingtask)) {
                    foreach ($pendingtask as $task_row) {
                        ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>milestone/viewMilestone/<?php echo $task_row->id; ?>">
                            <span class="task">
                                <span class="desc"><?php echo $task_row->title; ?></span>
                                <span class="percent">30%</span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="progress progress-success ">
                                <span style="width: 30%;" class="bar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="external">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>task">See all tasks <i class="m-icon-swapright"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- END TODO DROPDOWN -->  
    <?php } ?>
```

pagetopnavigation view

```
<!-- BEGIN HEADER -->   
<div class="header navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION BAR -->
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <?php $this->load->view('include/pagelogo'); ?>
            <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->              
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                <?php //$this->load->view('include/pagetopnotifications'); ?>
                <?php //$this->load->view('include/pagetopnewmessage'); ?>
                <?php $this->load->view('include/pagetoptodo', $pendingtask); ?>
                <?php $this->load->view('include/pagetopuserprofile'); ?>
            </ul>
            <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU --> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION BAR -->
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: what is this undefined variable name?. plz check the error log (apache error log)

Comment: this is error

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: pendingtask

Filename: include/pagetopnevigation.php

Line Number: 11

Comment: ok . so the error is on your view file (views/include/pagetopnavigation.php) . Check your controller which your are calling to execute this file . There you have declare value for this variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
?php $this->load->view('include/pagetoptodo', $pendingtask); ?>
```

is where your error is: the second parameter needs to be an array. So:

```
?php $this->load->view('include/pagetoptodo', array('pendingtask'=>$pendingtask)); ?>
```

in order to pass to a sub-view

Answer (score -1):

In Your pagetopnavigation view page you used the variable **"$pendingtask"**

```
(<?php $this->load->view('include/pagetoptodo', $pendingtask); ?>)
```

The error what you are getting is a Notice => it is saying the variable(**$pendingtask**) is not defined in your code ; it will not stop the execution of file, you can stop "Notice and Warning" messages by using error_reporting method or you can set up this in Codeigniter configurations, check this link for reference : http://phpdog.blogspot.in/2012/02/codeigniter-error-reporting-handling.html